# Parameters A and B must be determined such that for each x∈ℝ \ {1, -1, -2} the following equation is satisfied:

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing

$$\frac{(7x+2)(x+1)}{(x^2-1)(x+2)} = \frac A{x−1}+\frac B{x+2}$$

I never did such a task before. My first idea would be to shorten the left side by (x+1), which would result in.

$$\frac{7x+2}{(x^2-1)+1} = \frac A{x−1}+\frac B{x+2}$$ And that is utterly wrong. I asked in other forums and they said me that I have to get this term:

$$\frac{7x+2}{(x-1)(x+2)} = \frac {A(x+2)+B(x-1)}{(x-1)(x+2)}$$ With the solutions being $$(A+B)*x = 7x~and~ 2A - B = 2$$

I did not understand anything, how to get to these results in the first instance and how to calculate A and B. This is my one of my first "tasks" I have to do for the first semester, and I have no idea how to do it. Need help! =(

Comment: Have you ever learned algebra or have you completely forgotten it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you get

$$7x+2=A(x+2)+B(x-1)$$

rewwrite it as

$$7x+2=(A+B)x+(2A-B)$$

Hence by comparing the coefficient, you just have to solve for $A+B=7$ and $2=2A-B$.

$$2=2A-(7-A)=3A-7$$

$$3A=2+7=9$$

Hopefully you can solve for $A$ and $B$ from here.

Alternatively, after getting

$$7x+2=A(x+2)+B(x-1)$$

Let $x=1$, and we get $9=3A$ immediately.

Let $x=-2$, we get $-14+2=-3B$ immediately.

Comment: I did not even understand how I am supposed to get \frac{7x+2}{(x-1)(x+2)} = \frac {A(x+2)+B(x-1)}{(x-1)(x+2)} . It has been told to me, but I'd also like to understand how I can get there.

Comment: I see. Can you simplify $\frac13 + \frac14$? I am trying to find out where is the first point that you are stuck.

Comment: 1. Step: \frac412 + \frac312 2. Step \frac712 ? (still trying to figure out how to use the commands here) So the result is 7/12

Comment: Great, the strategy is to make the denominator the same. So the first term is $\frac{A}{x-1} = \frac{A(x+2)}{(x-1)(x+2)}$. For the second term, multiply the numerator and denominator  by $(x-1)$. Tips for typing, curly braces help.